# What’s the difference between formula and method?

Tags: meaning, differences, semantics

What's the difference between **formula** and **method**?

Their definitions given by a dictionary are pretty similar to mine:
*a set of actions taken in order to achieve something*.

My understanding is that formula is more specific than method like we need to do what when and how. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: In what context??   If you look at a recipe for pancakes, the "formula" is the measurements of the ingredients, while the "method" is the the way they are combined and cooked.

Comment: Formula usually doesn't change, but method does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/formula) definition adds a well-considered caveat:

> **formula** ... 4:
>
> a **customary or set** form or method **allowing little room for
>   originality**
>
> - *All her books were written according to a familiar formula.*

[bolding mine]

So a formula is an *established* method.

Other well-known senses of *formula* must also inform this usage at the subtext level: the chemical usage, the mathematical usage, the high-tech ('Formula 1' etc) usages. These put the word into the formal / qualified / adept / more sophisticated register. A complex series of steps is quite strongly implied.

While *method* can probably almost always be used in place of this sense of *formula* (with broadening, and loss of the connotations mentioned), *formula* is often the better choice. But by the same token, of course, often inappropriate.